# selecting with multiple where conditions and multiple order clauses from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause

first table: posts

```
ID   post    unix_timestamp  upvotes 
-----------------------------------
118  mmmm    1360662045       4 
119  kdkdk   1360662074       2
120  dkcjf   1360662012       3
121  dkcmv   1360662025       1
```

and some other fields

second table: post_tags

```
ID   post_id   tagname  
-----------------------
1    118        #test
2    118        #iseeyou
3    119        #sleepy
```

MYSQL query that i ran.

```
SELECT p.id, p.post, p.timestampfull FROM posts p,
post_tags pt WHERE pt.tagname IN ('#test','#iseeyou')
AND p.post LIKE  '%united states%'
AND p.id = pt.post_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT( pt.tagname ) = 2
ORDER BY p.upvotes DESC , p.unix_timestamp DESC
```

In my search application, i am trying to fetch the most recent rows that's why `p.unix_timestamp` also ordered by upvotes in descending order based on search query which can contain hash tags or plain text or both.

So, if user searches for `#test #iseeyou united states`, it should return posts which contain both tags and also the text united states ordered by time stamp and upvotes.

Also, i want the posts with higher upvotes take precedence over being the most recent.

Please advise if my query is correct?

Comment: you have sample records. and you have the query, when you executed it on the server, did you get the result you want?

Comment: i didn't get anything. it was an empty result set. Also, MYSQL didn't give any error too.

Comment: @JW hey, soory to bother you again, but i am just running this query on my DB and it is constantly giving me an empty result

Comment: what query are you executing? can you post it alng with your question? maybe you have something missing in your query..

Comment: no, i am using the exact same query that you posted. one thing i have noticed, that i have upvotes and unix_timestamp column as varchar type in my DB as in your demo, its INT. Does it affect the result?

Comment: i think it doesn't as i tried removing the `ORDER BY` clause and it still doesnt give anything.

Comment: can you give records that you tested? not the one on your question? so i can see where my statement gone wrong.

Comment: how do i give the records? maybe on SQL FIDDLE? i am checking, there is one post in my `posts` table which has a tag `#test` which is what i posted in the question. still, it fails to give anything back.

Comment: hey i just checked again and strangely turns out that all my tags have been inserted with a leading space that's why the query returns empty. phew, another task now is to investigate why spaces are being added in my `foreach` loop running on array returned by `preg_match`

Comment: oh that's strange. maybe you have extra space on you in your `insert` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    posts p
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.ID
            FROM    posts a
                    INNER JOIN post_tags b
                        ON a.ID = b.post_ID
            WHERE   a.post LIKE '%mmmm%' AND
                    b.tagname IN ('#test','#iseeyou')
            GROUP   BY ID
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagname) = 2
        ) sub ON p.ID = sub.ID
ORDER   BY p.upvotes DESC, p.unix_timestamp DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff7ed/7)

Comment: also, could you throw some light on the logic here, and if possible where i was wrong so that i do not commit the same mistake in future.

Comment: the reason why I'm wrapping your code with a subquery is because without subquery, it will only return one `ID` for every group since you have applied group on it. The outer query which joins the subquery will allow you to select all columns on the table post in which the `post.ID` is equal to `ID` projected on the subquery.